# Using PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent and java.lang.reflect

Tags: java, reflection, bukkit

I'm currently using `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent`.
I use syntax like this:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
public void PlayerCommandPreprocess(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event){
    String cmd;
    String args;
    if(event.getMessage().indexOf(" ") == -1){
        cmd = event.getMessage().substring(1);
        args = "";
        getLogger().info(String.format("%s used '%s'",event.getPlayer().getDisplayName(), cmd));
    }else{
        cmd = event.getMessage().substring(0, event.getMessage().indexOf(" ")).substring(1);
        args = event.getMessage().substring(event.getMessage().indexOf(" ")+1);
        getLogger().info(String.format("%s used '%s' with args '%s'",event.getPlayer().getDisplayName(), cmd, args));
    }

    switch(cmd){
        case "serverinfo":
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage("This server is running some sort of new plugin that is not finished yet.");
            event.setCancelled(true);
            break;
        case "spawn":
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage("So you wanted to teleport to spawn to save time, right?");
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage("This will teach you, cheater!");
            event.getPlayer().addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.POISON,1200,1));
            event.setCancelled(true);
            break;
        default:
            event.setCancelled(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

I would like to use separate methods inside of class `PlayerCommands`.
As this will be the only plugin used on the server, I want to capture all commands, evaluate whether they have its `PlayerCommands.cmd_<cmdname>()` and invoke it.

I know this is possible to do via `java.lang.reflect` but right now I just don't know how to implement it on a Bukkit server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `Class.forName()` to iterate through the methods and register them.